# How to monitor tasks in celery with SQS broker?

Tags: django, celery, monitoring

What could be a way to have a dashboard similar to **flower** to monitor the *celery tasks*. From the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html), I see that SQS monitoring support is not yet there. What could be another option?

I am using Django with celery.

Answer (score 1):

You're only other option, apart from using cloudwatch (https://dzone.com/articles/using-sqs-with-celery), is to build your own.  Fortunately you can do that with boto3.  You will have to "read" every message on the queue, but it will be in json format if you want task level details.  There are no pre-built libraries that I know of that already offer monitoring for django + celery + sqs.